# Swizzling UIResponder Touch events not invoking original method implementation

Tags: ios, swift, uitouch, objective-c-runtime, method-swizzling

I am trying to swizzle the `UITouch` lifecycle events by creating a `UIResponder` extension. Following is an excerpt depicting the implementation for `touchesBegan`.

```
 public extension UIResponder {

   private enum TouchPhase: String {
    case begin
    case move
    case end
    case cancel
    //computed property
    var phase: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

    @objc func swizztouchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
            UIEvent?) {
         print("swizztouchesBegan event called!")
         let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
         self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .begin)
         self.swizztouchesBegan(touches, with: event)
     }

    static func swizzleTouchesBegan() {
       let _: () = {
            let originalSelector = 
        #selector(UIResponder.touchesBegan(_:with:))
            let swizzledSelector = 
        #selector(UIResponder.swizztouchesBegan(_:with:))
             let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIResponder.self, originalSelector)
             let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIResponder.self, swizzledSelector)
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
    }()
 }
}
```

I am then invoking it in my app like so-

```
 [UIResponder swizzleTouchesBegan]; //my app is a mix of Objective-C and Swift
```

What I see is- "swizztouchesBegan event called!" gets printed and I get to create the dictionary of the touch metadata. However, it looks like it does not call the original implementation, e.g. let's say somewhere in my code, inside a table view controller, I write the following-

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    print("AM I GETTING CALLED?")
}
```

this overridden touchesBegan is not getting called- what could be the issue? I am already calling the original implementation from inside the swizzled one by calling the swizzled one again (thereby making sure the original one gets called.)

PS/ Addendum: I have been able to get it working by just overriding the touch methods in an `UIView` extension, like following. Can someone point out if there's any disadvantage using this approach over the swizzling one?

```
public extension UIView {

private enum TouchPhase: String {
    case begin
    case move
    case end
    case cancel
    //computed property
    var phase: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("overriding touches began event!")
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .begin)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

open override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("overriding touches moved event!")
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .move)
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)

}

open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("overriding touches ended event!")
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .end)
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

}

  open override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with 
 event: UIEvent?) {
    print("overriding touches canceled event!")
    let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
    self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .cancel)
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're swizzling the selector always without checking if that was already done.

here is a sample on how you can do it.

```
extension UIResponder {

    static let swizzleIfNeeded: () = {
        swizzle(originalSelector: #selector(touchesBegan(_:with:)), to: #selector(swizztouchesBegan(_:with:)))
    }()

    static func swizzle(originalSelector: Selector, to swizzledSelector: Selector) {
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
        let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod!))
        if didAddMethod {
            class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod!), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod!))
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!);
        }
    }

    @objc func swizztouchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("swizztouchesBegan event called!")
        let touch = touches.first! as UITouch
        self.createTouchesDict(for: touch, event: event, phase: .begin)
        self.swizztouchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

then in you app delegate did finish (for example)

```
UIResponder.swizzleIfNeeded
```

Comment: I tried your solution- I think it's an optimized one but it still did not solve the issue. The original impl is still not getting called. Because of this, let's say, if I tap on a cell in a UICollectionView,  it's didSelectItemAt delegate is not getting called. Not sure why's that happening.

Answer (score 0):

It seems method swizzle is not necessary for swift, because there are extensions.

So if you want to swizzle touch for any class you just override touch. like below I wanted to give bounce effect to all Bounce

```
extension UIView {
    func highlight(color: UIColor) {
        let anim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.backgroundColor))
        anim.fromValue = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        anim.toValue = color.cgColor
        anim.duration = 0.5
        anim.autoreverses = true
        anim.repeatCount = 0
        anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        self.layer.add(anim, forKey: "blink")
    }

    func bounce() {
        let endTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        let prepareTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
        UIView.animateKeyframes(
            withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeLinear, animations: {
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.1) {
                    self.transform = prepareTransform
                }
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.1, relativeDuration: 0.1) {
                    self.transform = endTransform
                }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension BounceButton {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.bounce()
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

But in your case you can do for all UIView extensions, so everything can be bounceable.